# как вывести один сайт вместо другого

Tags: php, redirect, cross-domain

есть сайт 1 по адресу  *exemple.com*

и сайт 2 *test.com*

можно ли с помощью php показать сайт *exemple.com* по адресу *test.com* 
без редиректа ?

Comment: http://htmlbook.ru/samhtml/freymy/sozdanie-freymov

Comment: `echo file_get_contents('http://exemple.com');`

Comment: например через настройку конфигурации http-сервера, для проксирования запросов к  test.com на exemple.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 - **Лучшее решение** - через конфиги NGINX настроить проксирование, подробнее можете прочитать здесь - https://serveradmin.ru/nginx-proxy_pass/

2 - **Легкое решение** - `echo file_get_contents('http://domain.com');`

**Помните что если будет много трафика с вашего сайта, то владелец сайта-донора быстро вас распознает, расценит как ДДОС и забанит IP**

Answer (score -1):

Можно на чистом HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
    <iframe src="example.com" width="100vw" height="100vh"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```